# how to initialize the "min" variable properly?

Tags: c, gcc, initialization

I have a small problem in my code for finding the minimum value from a series of numbers. When I initialize `min = 0`, the minimum value turns out as 0. But when I don't initialize `min`, the answer is correct!

Why does this happen? Xcode tells me I should initialize the `min` variable.

```
int a[20] = {0};
int max = 0;
int min ;
int sum = 0;

srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    a[i] = 100 + rand()%(200 - 100 + 1);

    if (max < a[i]) {
        max = a[i];
    }
    printf("%d,%d\n",a[i],i);

    if (min > a[i]) {
        min = a[i];
    }

    sum += a[i];
}

printf("最大值：%d\n",max);
printf("最小值：%d\n",min);
printf("平均值：%d\n",sum / 20);
```

Comment: What do you think `if (min > a[i])` does? Just initialize `min` to `INT_MAX` from `limits.h` and everything will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler warning is because accessing the value of uninitialised variables gives undefined behaviour.

A common technique to find a minimum value in an array is to initialise the `min` to be the first element in the array, then iterate over subsequent elements

```
 min = a[0];
 for (i = 1; i < 20; ++i)     /* assume 20 elements */
     if (a[i] < min) min = a[i];
```

This works for all numeric types that can be compared using the `<` operator, without having to muck around trying to find a value that exceeds all possible values in the array.

The other thing to watch is that array indexing starts at zero.  So an array with 20 elements  (as in `int a[20]`) has valid indices `0` to `19`.  Running a loop from `1` to `20` - and therefore accessing `a[1]` through to `a[20]` gives undefined behaviour, since `a[20]` does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't initialize a local variable, its value is *indeterminate*, and using that will lead to *undefined behavior*.

What you should do is initialize it to a *large* value, just like you initialize `max` to a *small* value. Use `INT_MAX` from the [`<limits.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits#Limits_of_integer_types) header file.

---

Also, if your variables can't be negative, you should probably use `unsigned int`, and initialize `min` to `UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 2):

> *When I initialize `min = 0`, the minimum value turns out as `0`.*

because in that case, `if (min > a[i])` is always false. Remeber, `a[i]` is > = 100.

> *But when I don't initialize `min`, the answer is correct!*

if you don't initalize the local variable, it's value in indeterminent and contains some garbage value (possibly a large one). So, *seemingly*, your logic works and you're *apparently* getting the *right* answer. However, using values of uninitalized local variable invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Solution:**
Initialize `min` with the largest possbile value, `INT_MAX` present in  header file.

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize `min` with a large number, otherwise `0` **might** remain as the smallest number.

You can initialize `min` as

```
int min = INT_MAX;
```

`INT_MAX` is the largest value that can be held by an `int`( Must add `<limits.h>` for `INT_MAX` ).

If you don't initialize `min` with a value, then it will have an indeterminate value, which can be anything, so always initialize your local variables before using their values..